# Mac Office 2011 VBA Word refer to already opened Excel Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, macos, ms-word, osx-yosemite

I really need some help. I have been searching for a solution for almost a month now (not constantly) but I couldn't find a way to make it work.

First of all this is the code I have to open the Workbook, which works perfectly well:

```
Private Sub OpenExcelDatabase()

    Dim oxl As Object
    Set oxl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Dim xlPath As String
    xlPath = "OSX:Users:" & GetUserName.GetUserName & ":Documents:Rechnungen:"

    Dim xlFile As String
    xlFile = "Database_Rechnungen.xlsm"

    oxl.Workbooks.Open (xlPath & xlFile)
    Application.ActiveWindow = ActiveDocument

    Dim xlWB As Object
    Set xlWB = oxl.Workbooks.Open(xlPath & xlFile)

    xlWB.Application.Run "connectSQL"

End Sub
```

Now I need to get some data from that Workbook for 2 different Userforms which are located in the new word document. In the VBA-menu I have already activated the Object-Library for Excel but the problem is that even though it seems to know the functions (it shows all the options that I would need), it can't run them. The thing is that I need to run a Macro which is located in the Workbook as soon as a commandbutton from a Userform in Word is pressed.

Maybe to clarify things:

I have a word-template which is used to write invoices. There are 2 (important) Userforms - SearchCompany and SearchPerson. In these two UserForms the user can enter a string and this string shall be searched in the excel-database-cells. If this string is existing in one of the searched cells, it shall return all the information of that company back to the UserForm. The same with the person. In my Workbook I have a sheet with the companies and one sheet with the people that work in the companies.

These are the codes I have already tried to refer to the opened Workbook or to run a macro in that Workbook:

```
1. xlWB.Application.Run "SearchFirma"

2. Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Application.Run "SearchFirma"

3. Excel.Workbooks("Database_Rechnungen.xlsm").Application.Run "SearchFirma"

4. Set xlWB = GetObject("Database_Rechnungen.xlsm")

5. Set xlWB = oxl.Workbooks("Database_Rechnungen.xlsm")

6. Set xlWB = Excel.Workbooks(1)
```

1. Run-time error '424' : Object required
2. Run-time error '91'  : Object variable or With block variable not set
3. Run-time error '51'  : Internal Error
4. Run-time error '424' : Object required
5. Run-time error '424' : Object required 'Maybe it was '51'
6. Run-time error '424' : Object required 'Maybe it was '51'

If I used the workbooks.Open-Method once again I get the error-message, that this workbook is already opened... The problem is that to get the information back to word I would also need to refer to an opened, yet not named or saved word-document ("document1").

Whatever I tried didn't work. I have searched half google for a solution, but no one has ever had such a problem... As soon as most people activated the object libraries, everything worked. Why doesn't it work with me? Is there anything else I need to check? (Object-library is existing)
The function getObject ain't working on mac, but maybe someone knows a workaround?
I would be unbelieveably thankful for everyone who tries to help me with this, as I am starting to get really desperate for finding a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it:

```
Private Sub Document_New()
    xlPath = "OSX:Users:" & GetUserName.GetUserName & ":Documents:Rechnungen:"
    xlFile = "Database_Rechnungen.xlsm"

    Call OpenExcFileWithApp(xlPath, xlFile, "connectSQL")
    UFFirmaSearch.Show

End Sub
```

And this is the function:

```
Public oxl As Object
Public xlWB As Object

Public xlPath As String
Public xlFile As String

Public FSearchText As String
Public FResult As ListBox

Function OpenExcFileWithApp(Path As String, File As String, RunMacro As String)

    Dim FileFullName As String
    FileFullName = Path & File

    Set oxl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWB = oxl.Workbooks.Open(FileFullName)

    If RunMacro <> "" Then
        xlWB.Application.Run RunMacro
    End If
End Function
```

With this everytime I use xlWB in my  word-Modules it refers to the opened Workbook. :)

Thank you Kiroshiro, as you brought me upon the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to "Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object library" in Words VBA- editor. This will give you access to the excel object model.

Then you could reference the application and workbooks like this:

```
Sub test()

    Dim ex  As New Excel.Application
    Dim wb  As Workbook

    Set wb = ex.Workbooks.Open("C:\TestVAs\TestBook.xlsx")

End Sub
```

Then you are able to call your macro from excel application.

```
ex.Run "YourWorkbookNameAndPath!YourMacroToCall"
```

Comment: I have already activated the object library, these are the error-codes I get after including the object library.... This is the big problem I have. Also do I not want to reopen the workbook but search for the data which corresponds to the data entered in the userform in word.

Comment: Ok, got it. The "workbbok" object has no procedure "Run". This is the Application object.

Comment: in my OpenExcelWorkbook-Sub xlWB.Application.Run "" is working perfectly well. so this can't be the problem....

Comment: I wrote a second answer. Making it clear hopefuly. :)

Comment: I saw it and maybe I have to be more clear: the code in OpenExcelDatabase() is working perfectly well. Everything including the run of the macro is proceeded. I cannot refer to that opened workbook from another module and everything like dim Xl as Excel.Application or as workbook or as worksheet doesn't work, even though the object library for excel IS ALREADY ACTIVATED. I cannot reopen the workbook so ex.workbooks.open doesn't work either. Also I am working on mac, saying that not all functions from windows are included. But I'll try it tomorrow and I'll tell you if it works. thank you :)

Comment: I'm sorry. I missed that it worked in your other sub. But looks wrong to me. See msdn reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/office/dn301170.aspx

Comment: IDEA: If opening a workbook works. Then you could copy the macro to your word file. Opening the workbook like you did it and then run the macro from word instead excel. This maybe the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The "workbbok" object has no procedure "Run".

1. xlWB.Application.Run "SearchFirma" <- This is maybe wrong because a workbbok object has no property "Application"
2. Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Application.Run "SearchFirma" <- This is maybe wrong because "Workbook" object has no property "Application".
3. Excel.Workbooks("Database_Rechnungen.xlsm").Application.Run "SearchFirma" <- This is maybe wrong because the "Workbbok" object has no property Application.
4. Set xlWB = GetObject("Database_Rechnungen.xlsm") <- This is wrong but I don't know why.
5. Set xlWB = oxl.Workbooks("Database_Rechnungen.xlsm") <- This is wrong.
6. Set xlWB = Excel.Workbooks(1)

Your call should look like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Ex as New Excel.Application
    Dim WB as Workbbok
    Dim Sh as Worksheet
    Dim Data as variant

    ' to a open workbook and read, write or delete data.
    ' Now you could manipulate the data with the "WB" variable.
    Set WB = Ex.Workbboks.Open("YourWorkbbokPathAndName")
    Set Sh = WB.Sheets("YourSheetName")
    ' recieve the data
    Data = Sh.cells.value

    ' do your stuff with Data

    ' write back data
    Sh.cells.value = data

    ' run a macro inside a workbbok
    ' This is the Application object. NOT a Workbook!
    Ex.Run "YourWorkbookPathAndName!YourMacroToCall"
End Sub
```